# List all DNS Servers, including those pushed by VPN

Tags: dns, vpn, networkmanager, openvpn, resolv.conf

I want to know which DNS servers are in effect when I run commands like nslookup, dig, host, ping, etc.

The general answer is to `cat /etc/resolv.conf`, or to look at NetworkManager, but that's only going to show me the list of servers that I normally use.  It won't show me any DNS servers that got pushed to me when I connect to a VPN.

Is there a way to get an in-order list of DNS servers that commands like nslookup, dig, host, ping, etc will attempt to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `NetworkManager` you can use the command line tool that's part of it, `nmcli` to get this list:

```
$ nmcli dev list iface wlan0 | grep IP4
IP4-SETTINGS.ADDRESS:           192.168.1.110
IP4-SETTINGS.PREFIX:            24 (255.255.255.0)
IP4-SETTINGS.GATEWAY:           192.168.1.1
IP4-DNS1.DNS:                   192.168.1.8
IP4-DNS2.DNS:                   192.168.1.5
IP4-DNS3.DNS:                   24.92.226.11
```

You have to change the bit, `wlan0` to whatever is your network interface. You can make it a bit more dynamic by using the `iwgetid` command:

```
$ nmcli dev list iface $(iwgetid | awk '{print $1}') | grep IP4
```

You can also use `nm-tool` to get a full report:

```
$ nm-tool 
...
  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.110
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.8
    DNS:             192.168.1.5
    DNS:             24.92.226.11
```

Comment: And what if I do not use NetworkManager?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost - ask your Q on the main site. This Q specifically dealt with NetworkManager. Notice it was tagged as such by the OP?

Comment: When I try to use nmcli on the tunneling interface "tun0" setup by my vpn, I get "Error: Device 'tun0' not found."

Comment: That did work. I used `nmcli d show enp2s0 | grep IP4`

Answer (score 0):

```
resolvectl status vpn0 
resolvectl status wlan0 
resolvectl status ...
```